# MacBook Pro 16-inch 2019 fans spikes up then restarts

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

I did a fresh install of Catalina and Big Sur on my MacBook Pro 2019 16 inch. Randomly, the fans speed spikes up, laptop hangs, then restarts.

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff0291cb8ec): ANS2 Recoverable Panic - assert failed: [11932]:MD_UNCORR_ERR F2H 1 SL[0] ERR 0x4000000 HIX 0 SEG 0 TAG 324 OP 0 DRAM 4294967294 LBA 0x78d742a secOffset 0x2 dp[e17e0000, 1000802, 78d742a, 7bd0] mmu[fffffffb, 3c848000, 4ff08, 2d04000, 80000000, 4300, 40f] - Upd
assert failed: [11932]:MD_UNCORR_ERR F2H 1 SL[0] ERR 0x4000000 HIX 0 SEG 0 TAG 324 OP 0 DRAM 4294967294 LBA 0x78d742a secOffset 0x2 dp[e17e0000, 1000802, 78d742a, 7bd0] mmu[fffffffb, 3c848000, 4ff08, 2d04000, 80000000, 4300, 40f]
RTKit: RTKit_iOS-1827.100.26.release - Client: t8012.release-AppleStorageProcessorANS2-1274.100.6~707~1274.100.6~707
!UUID: a7041e1c-ef4d-388c-9b6d-027240e3c6a0
Time: 0x0000000a27d4fdba

Faulting task   3 Call Stack: 0x0000000000015cbc 0x0000000000015778 0x0000000000015630 0x00000000000174c4 0x0000000000018eb4 0x0000000000018ee8 0x00000000000be454 0x00000000000bd714 0x000000000000f970 0x0000000000009c24 0x0000000000008df8 0x00000000000286f0 0x000000000002daf4 0x000000000002daf4 0x000000000008d904 0x0000000000036094 0x000000000000d720

Marin ASC Async error info: 
l2c_err_sts 0x10001bfc00000000, l2c_err_adr 000000000000000000, l2c_err_inf 000000000000000000
lsu_err_sts 000000000000000000, fed_err_sts 000000000000000000, mmu_err_sts 000000000000000000

Mailbox (0): (0)
  Inbox  AKF_KIC_INBOX_CTRL = 0x00020001, AKF_KIC_MAILBOX_SET = 0x00001101
  Outbox AKF_AP_OUTBOX_CTRL = 0x00020001, AKF_AP_MAILBOX_SET  = 0x00000000

    dir   endpoint      timestamp           msg
    ====  ============  ==================  ==================
    [RX]    management  0x000000000031e30c  0x00b0000000000020
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000031e40c  0x0050000000000000
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000031e414  0x0050000000000001
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000031e418  0x0050000000000002
    [TX]    management  0x000000000031e488  0x00b0000000000020
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000031ebb8  0x0050000000000000
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000031ec30  0x0050000000000001
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000031ecb0  0x0050000000000002
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000000326244  0x0050000000000003
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000000326328  0x0050000000000004
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000000326698  0x0050000000000003
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000000326728  0x0050000000000004
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000000e99f94  0x0050000000000005
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000000e9a094  0x0050000000000006
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000000e9ae34  0x0050000000000005
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000000e9b1f0  0x0050000000000006
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000004ae367a4  0x0050000000000007
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000004ae37224  0x0050000000000007
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000004b2492f0  0x0050000000000008
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000004b24a148  0x0050000000000008
    [RX]    management  0x000000004b24f548  0x00b0000000000201
    [TX]    management  0x000000004b24f730  0x00b0000000000201
    [RX]    management  0x000000004b2508d0  0x0060000000000201
    [TX]    management  0x00000000001166f4  0x00100000000c000c
    [RX]    management  0x000000000013e004  0x00200000000c000c
    [TX]    management  0x000000000013e124  0x008000000000001f
    [RX]    management  0x0000000000144794  0x008000000000001f
    [TX]    management  0x00000000001447c8  0x0088000100000003
    [RX]    management  0x00000000001502bc  0x0088000100000003
    [TX]        user02  0x00000000001507bc  0x0401000000000000
    [RX]        user02  0x000000000015aba0  0x0403000001010101
    [RX]        user02  0x000000000015ac0c  0x0205000000000000
    [TX]        user02  0x000000000015b790  0x0405000000000100
    [TX]        user02  0x000000000015b7c0  0x0305000000000000
    [RX]        user02  0x000000000015d2c8  0x0206000000000000
    [TX]        user02  0x000000000015d2e4  0x0306000000000000
    [RX]        user02  0x0000000000167170  0x0406000000000100
    [TX]        user02  0x000000000030f84c  0x0405000000000101
    [RX]        user02  0x000000000031e5d8  0x0406000000000101
    [TX]    management  0x0000000000401dec  0x0070000000000020
    [RX]    management  0x00000000004022f4  0x00b0000000000020
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000000402390  0x0050000000000000
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000000402398  0x0050000000000001
    [TX]    management  0x00000000004023e0  0x00b0000000000020
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000004025fc  0x0050000000000000
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000040267c  0x0050000000000001
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000000402f0c  0x0050000000000002
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000040322c  0x0050000000000002
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000040df60  0x0050000000000003
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000040e038  0x0050000000000004
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000040e3a4  0x0050000000000003
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000040e430  0x0050000000000004
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000000efccb8  0x0050000000000005
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000000efcdb4  0x0050000000000006
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000000efd9c8  0x0050000000000005
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000000efdf84  0x0050000000000006
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000000df0afd9c  0x0050000000000007
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000000df0afe84  0x0050000000000008
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000df0b0c7c  0x0050000000000007
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000df0b0ff4  0x0050000000000008
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000000ee3174fc  0x0050000000000009
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000000ee317608  0x005000000000000a
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000ee318208  0x0050000000000009
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000ee3185a0  0x005000000000000a
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000001ad6bbabc  0x005000000000000b
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000001ad6bbb0c  0x005000000000000c
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000001ad6bbc20  0x005000000000000d
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000001ad6bce3c  0x005000000000000b
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000001ad6bd164  0x005000000000000c
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000001ad6bdacc  0x005000000000000d
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000085162ccc4  0x005000000000000e
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000085162d448  0x005000000000000e
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000851a8c5e8  0x005000000000000f
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000851a8ccfc  0x005000000000000f
    [RX]    management  0x0000000851a8f6b8  0x00b0000000000201
    [TX]    management  0x0000000851a8f870  0x00b0000000000201
    [RX]    management  0x0000000851a90738  0x0060000000000201
    [TX]    management  0x000000000018c098  0x00100000000c000c
    [RX]    management  0x00000000001b2d5c  0x00200000000c000c
    [TX]    management  0x00000000001b2e64  0x008000000000001f
    [RX]    management  0x00000000001bf0d4  0x008000000000001f
    [TX]    management  0x00000000001bf0fc  0x0088000100000003
    [RX]    management  0x00000000001bf3dc  0x0088000100000003
    [TX]        user02  0x00000000001bf8d4  0x0401000000000000
    [RX]        user02  0x00000000001dbb58  0x0403000001010101
    [RX]        user02  0x00000000001dbce4  0x0205000000000000
    [TX]        user02  0x00000000001dc75c  0x0405000000000100
    [TX]        user02  0x00000000001dc78c  0x0305000000000000
    [RX]        user02  0x00000000001e0e40  0x0206000000000000
    [TX]        user02  0x00000000001e0e54  0x0306000000000000
    [RX]        user02  0x00000000001ecfb0  0x0406000000000100
    [TX]        user02  0x000000000038f94c  0x0405000000000101
    [RX]        user02  0x000000000039e2c8  0x0406000000000101
    [TX]    management  0x0000000000480670  0x0070000000000020
    [RX]    management  0x00000000004812d8  0x00b0000000000020
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000048137c  0x0050000000000000
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000000481384  0x0050000000000001
    [TX]    management  0x00000000004813c8  0x00b0000000000020
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000004817bc  0x0050000000000000
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000000481854  0x0050000000000001
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000000481890  0x0050000000000002
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000004824b0  0x0050000000000002
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000048c430  0x0050000000000003
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000048c514  0x0050000000000004
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000048ce50  0x0050000000000003
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000048ceec  0x0050000000000004
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000003b4d1e4  0x0050000000000005
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000003b4d2fc  0x0050000000000006
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000003b4dbbc  0x0050000000000005
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000003b4dd7c  0x0050000000000006
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000012bed4e8  0x0050000000000007
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000012bed5e4  0x0050000000000008
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000012bedbc4  0x0050000000000007
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000012bedda4  0x0050000000000008
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000001ad7171b0  0x0050000000000009
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000001ad71720c  0x005000000000000a
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000001ad717320  0x005000000000000b
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000001ad7181a4  0x0050000000000009
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000001ad7184a8  0x005000000000000a
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000001ad7189b0  0x005000000000000b
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000694037c58  0x005000000000000c
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000694037d48  0x005000000000000d
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000006940385c0  0x005000000000000c
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000006940387ac  0x005000000000000d
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000006a2ab3704  0x005000000000000e
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000006a2ab3800  0x005000000000000f
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000006a2ab4364  0x005000000000000e
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000006a2ab46e0  0x005000000000000f
RTKit Task List:
   name                    | pri     | stack use | status     | resource | warning
 0 rtk_ep_work             | 057     |   752/2048  | SEMWAIT    | 0x17ee20 | 
      0x000000000000cef0 0x000000000000dc48 0x000000000001601c 0x000000000000d720

 1 smc_mbox_work_loop      | 016     |   920/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0x17d740 | 
      0x000000000000cec0 0x000000000000dc48 0x000000000001601c 0x000000000000d720

 2 Null                    | 015     |   752/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0x1793c0 | 
      0x000000000000cef0 0x000000000000dc48 0x00000000001145f0 0x0000000000036094 0x000000000000d720

 3 Update                  | 015     |  1600/4096  | RUNNABLE   | 0 | [Faulting task]

 4 GC                      | 015     |  1536/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0x176b60 | 
      0x000000000000cec0 0x000000000000dc48 0x000000000008c2a0 0x0000000000036094 0x000000000000d720

 5 BG                      | 015     |  2112/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0x1754a0 | 
      0x000000000000cef0 0x000000000000dc48 0x000000000004a2e4 0x0000000000036094 0x000000000000d720

 6 Push                    | 015     |  1568/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0x174290 | 
      0x000000000000cef0 0x000000000000dc48 0x00000000000988d4 0x0000000000036094 0x000000000000d720

 7 Raid                    | 015     |  1344/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0x172b20 | 
      0x000000000000cec0 0x000000000000dc48 0x00000000000f6b9c 0x00000000000e8a28 0x00000000000e1b10 0x00000000000e3b5c 0x0000000000036094 0x000000000000d720

 8 PreNand                 | 015     |   928/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0xffffffff620ffee0 | 
      0x000000000000cec0 0x000000000000dc48 0x00000000000379f4 0x0000000000036094 0x000000000000d720

 9 DataXfer                | 015     |   608/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0xffffffff620fef10 | 
      0x000000000000cec0 0x000000000000dc48 0x00000000000d951c 0x0000000000036094 0x000000000000d720

10 PostNand                | 015     |   768/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0xffffffff620fde90 | 
      0x000000000000cec0 0x000000000000dc48 0x0000000000117f8c 0x0000000000036094 0x000000000000d720

11 Cmd                     | 015     |  2112/8192  | SEMWAIT    | 0xffffffff620fcd70 | 
      0x000000000000cec0 0x000000000000dc48 0x0000000000097df0 0x0000000000056b30 0x0000000000112980 0x0000000000036094 0x000000000000d720

12 Timer                   | 015     |   880/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0xffffffff620fa980 | 
      0x000000000000cec0 0x000000000000dc48 0x000000000004c884 0x0000000000036094 0x000000000000d720

13 power                   | 000     |  1168/4096  | WAITING    | 0x1461b8 | 
      0x000000000000cef0 0x000000000000d54c 0x0000000000014958 0x000000000000d720

14 System Thread           | 015     |   944/4096  | SUSPENDED  | 0 | 
      0x000000000000cec0 0x000000000000d54c 0x000000000000a1f8

15 aspcore timer tick      | 061     |   272/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0xffffffff620f7d20 | 
      0x000000000000cec0 0x000000000000dc48 0x0000000000036178 0x000000000000d720


APCIE 0
  Link 0: Present, link up (Gen3 X1), ltssm 0x14(L1_IDLE), VID/DID 0x106b/0x2004, linksts 0x9b02143d, pcielint 0x00003000
    L-state entries: [L0] 1341897 [L1.0] 1919941 [L1.1] 7 [L1.2] 578037 
  Link 1: Present, link up (Gen3 X1), ltssm 0x14(L1_IDLE), VID/DID 0x106b/0x2004, linksts 0x9b02143d, pcielint 0x00003000
    L-state entries: [L0] 1877636 [L1.0] 2458951 [L1.1] 2444 [L1.2] 579207 
  Link 2: Present, link up (Gen3 X1), ltssm 0x14(L1_IDLE), VID/DID 0x106b/0x2004, linksts 0x9b02143d, pcielint 0x00003000
    L-state entries: [L0] 1874110 [L1.0] 2447874 [L1.1] 7 [L1.2] 573757 
  Link 3: Present, link up (Gen3 X1), ltssm 0x14(L1_IDLE), VID/DID 0x106b/0x2004, linksts 0x9b02143d, pcielint 0x00003000
    L-state entries: [L0] 1859749 [L1.0] 2430818 [L1.1] 7 [L1.2] 571062 

APCIE 1
  Link 0: Present, link up (Gen3 X1), ltssm 0x14(L1_IDLE), VID/DID 0x106b/0x2004, linksts 0x9b02143d, pcielint 0x00003000
    L-state entries: [L0] 1331703 [L1.0] 1965516 [L1.1] 7 [L1.2] 633806 
  Link 1: Empty, link disabled
  Link 2: Empty, link disabled
  Link 3: Empty, link disabled

NVME 0
  CC: 0x00470001, CSTS: 0x00000001
  Admin SQ: 0x8068e8000, size: 65, tail/head: 5/5
  Admin CQ: 0x806920000, size: 65, tail/head: 5/5
  I/O SQ  : 0x8068ec000, size: 65, tail/head: 2/2
  I/O CQ  : 0x8068e4000, size: 65, tail/head: 2/2

NVME 1
  ID: macOS 20G80
  CC: 0x00470001, CSTS: 0x00000001
  Admin SQ: 0x000214000, size: 129, tail/head: 70/70
  Admin CQ: 0x000207000, size: 129, tail/head: 70/70
  I/O SQ  : 0x000218000, size: 129, tail/head: 92/92
  I/O CQ  : 0x000206000, size: 129, tail/head: 91/91
 
Nand_Desc : 0x31931d
Unmasked HWINTMON [0] 0x0
Unmasked HWINTMON [1] 0x0
Unmasked HWINTMON [2] 0x0
Unmasked HWINTMON [3] 0x0
     
ASP summary:
HR=0xe3a7084e HW=0x71616b87 CW=0x6048f5 NR=0xc35dbdae NW=0x68be9e58 M=0 Bu=641 Bi=171 D=0,0 V=357866KB BF=1,25 L=0 Q=0,12 E=0x4355 debugTrigger=0
KE=0x20 KY=0x0 KD=0x0 KT=0x64217b LA=0x27d4f5ee KW=0xfffc KQ=0
KT: EV=2 id=1
0-0x27d49d9c 1-0x27d4f5ee 2-0x94205123 3-0x27960f68 4-0x27d4eea5 5-0x27d4f221 6-0x27d4c50c 7-0x27d4f203 8-0x27d4ebbc 9-0x27d4c4fb 10-0x27ba9c14 
KLA=0x27d4f5ee LSSTS=0x27ba9cf8 DIFF=0x1a58f6 Plf=0x0 SPw=0x0 SPtwc=0x0
FBB=0x120 GBB=0xa6 RXBD=0x0 RB=0x0 PROB=0x0
UB=0x236 UECC=0x97 IUECC=0x842 PFAIL=0x0 EFAIL=0x0 CPF=0x0 CRF=0x0 RRFH=0x127 RRFI=0x0 E2EF=0x0
FWU 0x4 
Intr cycles: min=0x320 max=0x322 ave=0x321 
User cycles: min=0x16 max=0x1d ave=0x17 
F[0]=59 F[1]=0 F[2]=0 F[3]=0 F[4]=14 F[5]=93 F[6]=0 F[7]=1 F[8]=2 F[9]=0 F[10]=2 F[11]=0 F[12]=641 F[13]=171 F[14]=2 F[15]=1 F[16]=7 F[17]=1 F[18]=5 F[19]=7 
B: GM=0 S=7

MSP FW Version: msp_core_toshiba_itlc_3d_g4_2p_256-75.35.0

Buf: U=1 W=0

SegP:
  W=0 LT=5060 LWC=10121 LWCFS=10361
  Shared: C=11852 S=11 E=11868 F=3713
  Shared: C=4504 S=11869 E=16383 F=11987
  Prefetch: C=0 S=17935 E=18062 F=18063
  Cache: C=1260 S=16384 E=17934 F=0

SegQs:
  hostTime: hT[0]=0x27ce8e20 hT[1]=0x0 hT[2]=0x0 hT[3]=0x0 
SegQs.cmdQ
 [0]:FF00, FF00, 0
 [1]:FF01, FF01, 0
 [2]:FF02, FF02, 0
 [3]:FF03, FF03, 0
 [4]:FF04, FF04, 0
 [5]:FF05, FF05, 0
 [6]:FF06, FF06, 0
 [7]:FF07, FF07, 0
 [8]:FF08, FF08, 0
 [9]:FF09, FF09, 0
SegQs.retryQ
 [0]:FF0A, FF0A, 0
 [1]:FF0B, FF0B, 0
 [2]:FF0C, FF0C, 0
 [3]:FF0D, FF0D, 0
SegQs.writeQ
 [0]:FF0E, FF0E, 0
 [1]:FF0F, FF0F, 0
 [2]:FF10, FF10, 0
 [3]:FF11, FF11, 0
 [4]:FF12, FF12, 0
 [5]:FF13, FF13, 0
 [6]:FF14, FF14, 0
 [7]:FF15, FF15, 0
 [8]:FF16, FF16, 0
 [9]:FF17, FF17, 0
 [10]:FF18, FF18, 0
 [11]:FF19, FF19, 0
 [12]:FF1A, FF1A, 0
 [13]:FF1B, FF1B, 0
 [14]:FF1C, FF1C, 0
 [15]:FF1D, FF1D, 0
 [16]:FF1E, FF1E, 0
 [17]:FF1F, FF1F, 0
 [18]:FF20, FF20, 0
 [19]:FF21, FF21, 0
SegQs.writtenQ
 [0]:FF22, FF22, 0
 [1]:FF23, FF23, 0
 [2]:FF24, FF24, 0
 [3]:FF25, FF25, 0
 [4]:FF26, FF26, 0
 [5]:FF27, FF27, 0
 [6]:FF28, FF28, 0
 [7]:FF29, FF29, 0
 [8]:FF2A, FF2A, 0
 [9]:FF2B, FF2B, 0
 [10]:FF2C, FF2C, 0
 [11]:FF2D, FF2D, 0
 [12]:FF2E, FF2E, 0
 [13]:FF2F, FF2F, 0
 [14]:FF30, FF30, 0
 [15]:FF31, FF31, 0
 [16]:FF32, FF32, 0
 [17]:FF33, FF33, 0
 [18]:FF34, FF34, 0
 [19]:FF35, FF35, 0
SegQs.wipQ_GC
 [0]:FF36, FF36, 0
SegQs.wipQ_nonGC
 [0]:FF37, FF37, 0
SegQs.recvDataQ
 [0]:FF38, FF38, 0
SegQs.sendDataQ
 [0]:FF39, FF39, 0
SegQs.utilPend
 [0]:FF3A, FF3A, 0
SegQs.clogPool
 [0]:4, 2, 16
SegQs.Lonly
 [0]:FF3C, FF3C, 0
SegQs.pushPagesQ
 [0]:FF3D, FF3D, 0
SegQs.gcReads
 [0]:FF3E, FF3E, 0
SegQs.eanReads
 [0]:FF3F, FF3F, 0
SegQs.paritySavedQ
 [0]:FF40, FF40, 0
 [1]:FF41, FF41, 0
 [2]:FF42, FF42, 0
 [3]:FF43, FF43, 0
 [4]:FF44, FF44, 0
 [5]:FF45, FF45, 0
 [6]:FF46, FF46, 0
 [7]:FF47, FF47, 0
 [8]:FF48, FF48, 0
 [9]:FF49, FF49, 0
 [10]:FF4A, FF4A, 0
 [11]:FF4B, FF4B, 0
 [12]:FF4C, FF4C, 0
 [13]:FF4D, FF4D, 0
 [14]:FF4E, FF4E, 0
 [15]:FF4F, FF4F, 0
 [16]:FF50, FF50, 0
 [17]:FF51, FF51, 0
 [18]:FF52, FF52, 0
 [19]:FF53, FF53, 0
SegQs.pendingUnitCompleteQ
 [0]:FF54, FF54, 0
 [1]:FF55, FF55, 0
 [2]:FF56, FF56, 0
 [3]:FF57, FF57, 0
 [4]:FF58, FF58, 0
 [5]:FF59, FF59, 0
 [6]:FF5A, FF5A, 0
 [7]:FF5B, FF5B, 0
 [8]:FF5C, FF5C, 0
 [9]:FF5D, FF5D, 0
 [10]:FF5E, FF5E, 0
 [11]:FF5F, FF5F, 0
 [12]:FF60, FF60, 0
 [13]:FF61, FF61, 0
 [14]:FF62, FF62, 0
 [15]:FF63, FF63, 0
 [16]:FF64, FF64, 0
 [17]:FF65, FF65, 0
 [18]:FF66, FF66, 0
 [19]:FF67, FF67, 0
SegQs.cache_FS_CleanQ
 [0]:40F4, 40C7, 70400
SegQs.cacheDirtyQ
 [0]:FF69, FF69, 0
 [1]:FF6A, FF6A, 0
SegQs.cachePendQ
 [0]:FF6B, FF6B, 0
 [1]:FF6C, FF6C, 0
 [2]:FF6D, FF6D, 0
 [3]:FF6E, FF6E, 0
SegQs.prefetchActiveQ
 [0]:463E, 4610, 4096
SegQs.prefetchFreeQ
 [0]:FF70, FF70, 0
SegQs.clogLoadUpdateQ
 [0]:FF71, FF71, 0
SegQs.clogPortableQ
 [0]:FF72, FF72, 0
SegQs.clogPortableDoneQ
 [0]:FF73, FF73, 0
SegQs.stolenQ
 [0]:FF74, FF74, 0
SegQs.gcNoBlog
 [0]:FF75, FF75, 0
SegQs.raidSaveSegQ
 [0]:2E99, 2E99, 1
SegQs.raidInBandParityWipQ
 [0]:FF77, FF77, 0
SegQs.parityGenerateQ
 [0]:FF78, FF78, 0
BP:
 Mode Estimates:
    0 | SLC estimate 1256, MLC/TLC estimate 1256
    1 | SLC estimate 1256, MLC/TLC estimate 1256
    2 | SLC estimate 1256, MLC/TLC estimate 1256
     L estimate 4000

BP:
 Budgeting:
    0 | Budget 2147483647 Adjust 0
    1 | Budget 2147483647 Adjust 0
    2 | Budget 2147483647 Adjust 0
    3 | Budget 2147483647 Adjust 0
    4 | Budget 2147483647 Adjust 0

Wos:
  mLH=0x0 hIM=0x16 hBIM=0x2d lRM=0x641eac lWP=0x0 hP=0x57e40 hE=0x0 hN=0x0 sSE=0x0 sSN=0x0 bET1=0x0
lWM[0]=0x64216a lWM[1]=0x641993 lWM[2]=0x641eea lWM[3]=0x64214e   td=0x1000 hXW=0x0 FScc=0x113 FSec=0x0 FStc=0x113 FSus=0x1 Cds=0x0 ES=0x0 ePFM=0x0 FSW=0 uFS=1 uDS=1 s=1

Thermal Throttle Levels:  read: 0, prog: 0, comm: 0

Fences:
  fgen:  [0 - 29] [1 - 29] [2 - 29] [3 - 29] 
  fsec:  [0 - 0] [1 - 0] [2 - 0] [3 - 0] [4 - 0] [5 - 0] [6 - 0] [7 - 0] [8 - 0] [9 - 0] [10 - 0] [11 - 0] [12 - 0] [13 - 0] [14 - 0] [15 - 0] [16 - 0] [17 - 0] [18 - 0] [19 - 0] [20 - 0] [21 - 0] [22 - 0] [23 - 0] [24 - 0] [25 - 0] [26 - 0] [27 - 0] [28 - 0] [29 - 0] [30 - 0] [31 - 0] [32 - 0] [33 - 0] [34 - 0] [35 - 0] [36 - 0] [37 - 0] [38 - 0] [39 - 0] [40 - 0] [41 - 0] [42 - 0] [43 - 0] [44 - 0] [45 - 0] [46 - 0] [47 - 0] [48 - 0] [49 - 0] [50 - 0] [51 - 0] [52 - 0] [53 - 0] [54 - 0] [55 - 0] [56 - 0] [57 - 0] [58 - 0] [59 - 0] [60 - 0] [61 - 0] [62 - 0] [63 - 0] [64 - 0] [65 - 0] [66 - 0] [67 - 0] [68 - 0] [69 - 0] [70 - 0] [71 - 0] [72 - 0] [73 - 0] [74 - 0] [75 - 0] [76 - 0] [77 - 0] [78 - 0] [79 - 0] [80 - 0] [81 - 0] [82 - 0] [83 - 0] [84 - 0] [85 - 0] [86 - 0] [87 - 0] [88 - 0] [89 - 0] [90 - 0] [91 - 0] [92 - 0] [93 - 0] [94 - 0] [95 - 0] [96 - 0] [97 - 0] [98 - 0] [99 - 0] [100 - 0] [101 - 0] [102 - 0] [103 - 0] [104 - 0] [105 - 0] [106 - 0] [107 - 0] [108 - 0] [109 - 0] [110 - 0] [111 - 0] [112 - 0] [113 - 0] [114 - 0] [115 - 0] [116 - 0] [117 - 0] [118 - 0] [119 - 0] [120 - 0] [121 - 0] [122 - 0] [123 - 0] [124 - 0] [125 - 0] [126 - 0] [127 - 0] [128 - 0] [129 - 0] [130 - 0] [131 - 0] [132 - 0] [133 - 0] [134 - 0] [135 - 0] [136 - 0] [137 - 0] [138 - 0] [139 - 0] [140 - 0] [141 - 0] [142 - 0] [143 - 0] [144 - 0] [145 - 0] [146 - 0] [147 - 0] [148 - 0] [149 - 0] [150 - 0] [151 - 0] [152 - 0] [153 - 0] [154 - 0] [155 - 0] [156 - 0] [157 - 0] [158 - 0] [159 - 0] [160 - 0] [161 - 0] [162 - 0] [163 - 0] [164 - 0] [165 - 0] [166 - 0] [167 - 0] [168 - 0] [169 - 0] [170 - 0] [171 - 0] [172 - 0] [173 - 0] [174 - 0] [175 - 0] [176 - 0] [177 - 0] [178 - 0] [179 - 0] [180 - 0] [181 - 0] [182 - 0] [183 - 0] [184 - 0] [185 - 0] [186 - 0] [187 - 0] [188 - 0] [189 - 0] [190 - 0] [191 - 0] [192 - 0] [193 - 0] [194 - 0] [195 - 0] [196 - 0] [197 - 0] [198 - 0] [199 - 0] [200 - 0] [201 - 0] [202 - 0] [203 - 0] [204 - 0] [205 - 0] [206 - 0] [207 - 0] [208 - 0] [209 - 0] [210 - 0] [211 - 0] [212 - 0] [213 - 0] [214 - 0] [215 - 0] [216 - 0] [217 - 0] [218 - 0] [219 - 0] [220 - 0] [221 - 0] [222 - 0] [223 - 0] [224 - 0] [225 - 0] [226 - 0] [227 - 0] [228 - 0] [229 - 0] [230 - 0] [231 - 0] [232 - 0] [233 - 0] [234 - 0] [235 - 0] [236 - 0] [237 - 0] [238 - 0] [239 - 0] [240 - 0] [241 - 0] [242 - 0] [243 - 0] [244 - 0] [245 - 0] [246 - 0] [247 - 0] [248 - 0] [249 - 0] [250 - 0] [251 - 0] [252 - 0] [253 - 0] [254 - 0] [255 - 0] 
NVRAM value string [40A0DDD2-77F8-4392-B4A3-1E7304206516:storage-prev-assert]:[0x64d057f8,11932,1,0,67108864]
Failed to write NVRAM value string '40A0DDD2-77F8-4392-B4A3-1E7304206516:storage-prev-assert':'0x64d057f8,11932,1,0,67108864'
NVRAM value string [40A0DDD2-77F8-4392-B4A3-1E7304206516:storage-prev-assert-stored]:[0x64d057f8,0]
Failed to write NVRAM value string '40A0DDD2-77F8-4392-B4A3-1E7304206516:storage-prev-assert-stored':'0x64d057f8,0'
Sleep Count: 23708
Wake Count:  22458
Duty Cycle:  106

Buf:
  mgrCC: fC=0x211 w=0x0 hW=0x3 mE=0x200 bI=0x1eae9 E->s=0x27b E->e=0x48c
  mgrCC ranges:  0{0x1eae9,0x1ef75}  1{0xffffffff,0xffffffff}  
  mgrGP: fC=0x1bc0 w=0x0 hW=0x19 mE=0x34ec bI=0x19511 E->s=0x0 E->e=0x1bc0
  mgrGP ranges:  0{0x19511,0x1b0d1}  1{0xffffffff,0xffffffff}  
  mgrGC: fC=0x0 w=0x0 hW=0x5 mE=0x1e1 bI=0x1ad11 E->s=0xffff E->e=0xffff
  mgrGC ranges:  0{0xffffffff,0xffffffff}  1{0xffffffff,0xffffffff}  
Sleep Count: 23708
Wake Count:  22458
Duty Cycle:  106

RTBuddy(AP): Debug info:
_iopStatus = 0x8
_powerStateChangeLocked = false
Mailbox Status:
IDLE_STATUS: 0x00000028
MAILBOX_SET: 0x00000000
MAILBOX_CLR: 0x00000000
INBOX_CTRL: 0x00020001
OUTBOX_CTRL: 0x00021101

Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 19P4242
macOS version: 20G80
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.4.0: Mon Feb 21 20:11:10 PST 2022; root:xnu-8020.101.4~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: E6F1BA8F-E69D-3228-BA00-99812FF9CBEF
iBoot version: iBoot-7459.101.2
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0x16
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x1
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x405060400
PCIeUp link state: 0x89271611
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:      0x0000000021260000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff028264000
mach_absolute_time: 0x43bb948160
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x64cf9ede 0x0001838f
  Sleep   : 0x64cfca00 0x000ee165
  Wake    : 0x64d050df 0x0001bd82
  Calendar: 0x64d057f8 0x00051bf6

Zone info:
  Foreign : 0xfffffff05c1b4000 - 0xfffffff05c1c4000
  Native  : 0xffffffe0001ec000 - 0xffffffe6001ec000
  Readonly: 0xffffffe0e6850000 - 0xffffffe13351c000
  Metadata: 0xffffffeb008fc000 - 0xffffffeb04a6c000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffeb020fc000 - 0xffffffeb0235c000

CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 1: PC=0xfffffff028a9b070, LR=0xfffffff028a9b070, FP=0xffffffeb0467bf00
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Panicked task 0xffffffe219c64628: 0 pages, 230 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe3e6769500, backtrace: 0xffffffeb025037f0, tid: 400
          lr: 0xfffffff028a6ab08  fp: 0xffffffeb02503830
          lr: 0xfffffff028a6a890  fp: 0xffffffeb025038a0
          lr: 0xfffffff028ba2e64  fp: 0xffffffeb02503910
          lr: 0xfffffff028ba2018  fp: 0xffffffeb025039c0
          lr: 0xfffffff0290cd5fc  fp: 0xffffffeb025039d0
          lr: 0xfffffff028a6a5ac  fp: 0xffffffeb02503d60
          lr: 0xfffffff028a6a5ac  fp: 0xffffffeb02503dc0
          lr: 0xfffffff029be74c8  fp: 0xffffffeb02503de0
          lr: 0xfffffff0291cb8ec  fp: 0xffffffeb02503e70
          lr: 0xfffffff0291af578  fp: 0xffffffeb02503ea0
          lr: 0xfffffff029013abc  fp: 0xffffffeb02503ee0
          lr: 0xfffffff02901339c  fp: 0xffffffeb02503f20
          lr: 0xfffffff0290d85a0  fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

UPDATE:

I am attaching the diagnostic report from EtreCheck [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/m98kfmimejg5grfd07v3i/MBP-2019-EtreCheck-Report-08.08.23.rtf?rlkey=wjozqmd0bqbrm0ubejgd61xm8&dl=0).

Comment: Does this still occur in Safe Boot mode, or in a new user account? And what do you mean "an install of Catalina and Big sur"? Separate volumes, or just one after another?

Comment: yes, still happens on Safe mode and even on new user account. I tried installing fresh copy of both Catalina and Big Sur, not on separate volumes but reformatted and did a clean install. but still the issue persists. correct, one after another

Comment: Have you run the Diagnostic Hardware check? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202731

Comment: Yes, I already did. I did it just now also and there are no issues found - ADP000

Comment: The MacBook Pro models Apple released in the few years prior to late 2020, especially the 16" models, are known to be prone to sudden heating because of the Turbo Boost feature of the Intel processors used. Maybe [this answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252859218?answerId=255376032022#255376032022) (and the app mentioned in it) in another site to a partly related question about another 16" 2019 MBP might help. It definitely helped me with my 13" 2019 MBP.

Comment: In addition to [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) you already seem to have run, it might help to install and run [EtreCheck](https://etrecheck.com/en/welcome.html) and include its results in your answer.

Comment: @Alper Thank you for this! Will definitely try these apps! I've also tried and have EtreCheck already. I can share with you the report if you like. Thanks

Comment: No problem. It is better if you put EtreCheck’s diagnosis in your answer so that others can also take a look. I also suggest you read the lengthy answer in the duplicate carefully and try to figure out if any of the suggestions could apply in your case. If none of those apply and you wish to ask something further, you can update your question and ask for it to be reopened.

Comment: I haven't noticed anything that might cause the problem you are describing in the EtreCheck report but I am no expert. I suggest you install the free version of Turbo Boost Switcher, disable the processor's Turbo Boost and see if the problem recurs. However, even if this helps, it may not be the ultimate solution. While Turbo Boost causes the processor to frequently heat up rapidly and therefore the spiking of the fans, it should not be causing the freezing and the restarting. So, this also sounds like a faulty hardware problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys! I ended up returning the unit to the seller and get a refund! Its giving me too much headache! I went back in using my MBP 2018 15" with defective touchbar lol!